# Flex Slider Integration with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, flexslider

[SOLVED]

I'm trying to integrate Flex Slider (flexslider.woothemes.com) with WordPress. I've included all JS/CSS files needed.

Then, I added this code to show the featured images of a certain category - the famous WP_Query with $args set to a certain category. Then using echo the_post_thumbnail(); I'm showing the posts' images. It's working fine. I just need to make the images linked to post URLs (imgs are hrefed). Please provide help and thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
'category_name' => 'one',
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        );  

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Check if the Query returns any posts
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Start the Slider ?>
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">

                    <?php
                    // The Loop
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
<?php }
                        // The Slide's Image

                        echo the_post_thumbnail();

                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul><!-- .slides -->
            </div><!-- .flexslider -->

        <?php 

        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

---

New code that's working:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
'category_name' => 'one',
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        );  

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Check if the Query returns any posts
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Start the Slider 
?>

      <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">

                    <?php
                    // The Loop
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
 <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

</a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul><!-- .slides -->
            </div><!-- .flexslider -->

        <?php }

        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think the answer is

`echo '<a href="'. the_permalink() .'">';
echo the_post_thumbnail();
echo '</a>';`

Comment: are you trying to wrap your image in a link to the relevant post? Did I understand that part right?